# Zip folder in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have question. In Pentaho I created folder in instruction:

```
    IF not exist "D:\DIR_TEST\DIR_%DATE%\" ( mkdir "D:\DIR_TEST\DIR_%DATE%\" 
 ) ELSE ( echo "DIR exists"  )
```

In result I have each day other name dir. I have e.g. DIR_2021-02-15, DIR_2021-02-16 and other.
Each day in DIR_%DATE% I supplied files with this day.
I want to do zip DIR_%DATE%, but for example:
today is 2021-02-16 and this dir is during supply
yesterday was 2021-02-15 and this dir isn't supplied.

I would like zip only yesterday folder.
Whether anyone has idea?

Comment: Your description is clear. But can you please clear your question (in example). Its not clear i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do it simple:
Step 1, generate yesterday in string format YYYY-MM-DD.
Step 2, using zip file step in "Pentaho Job"(Not Transformation).

Here is my job:
[image]

Zip file step:

[image]